# How would I write NumPy argmode()?

Tags: python, math, numpy

I know that `argmax()` returns the indices of the maximum values along an axis.

I also know that in the case of multiple occurrences of the maximum values, the index corresponding to the first occurrence is returned.

`argmax()` works perfectly when you want to find the maximum value and its index. How would a numpy.argmode() function be written?

In other words how would a function that calculates the mode value in a numpy array and gets the index of the first occurrence be written?

*Just so everyone knows there is no numpy.argmode but the functionality of such a function is what I seek.*

I understand that the mode would have multiple occurrences. We should be able to get it to behave like argmax where if we have multiple occurrences, it simply returns the value and index of the first occurrence.

An example of what I would want is:

```
a = numpy.array([ 6, 3, 4, 1, 2, 2, 2])
numberIWant = numpy.argmode(a)
print(numberIWant)
# should print 4 (the index of the first occurrence of the mode)
```

I tried using:

```
stats.mode(a)[0][0]
numpy.argwhere(a==num)[0][0]
```

This did work but I'm looking for a more efficient and concise solution.
Any ideas?

Comment: I'd say what you have looks good, but `scipy.stats.mode` appears to have a [surprisingly naive implementation](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/stats/stats.py#L375), taking time proportional to `len(a)*len(set(a))` for a 1-dimensional `a`. It took 27.6 seconds to compute `scipy.stats.mode(numpy.arange(100000))`. Besides that, the natural ways of computing a mode don't seem like tracking indices simultaneously would be an efficiency improvement, so making another pass for the index seems fine.

Comment: Refering to `numpy.argmode` as though there really is such a numpy function is confusing.  There isn't such a function, and even if you write it, you probably don't want to add it to module.  In any case, 'mode' is an awkward statistic, that doesn't work like `sum`, `mean`, `max` etc.  Look at the code to stats.mode

Comment: Yes that is correct, numpy.argmode does not exist. What I was saying is that there is no argmode but I seek some source code for such a function. I am using this with numpy's fft algorithm and trying to retrieve the mode frequency that my microphone picks up when recording. Currently it only picks up the max which is what most solutions do. This is not ideal though because this doesn't account for "noise" or interference to the frequencies I want to pick up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to stay within NumPy, you can use some of the extra returns of [`np.unique`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) to get what you want:

```
>>> _, idx, cnt = np.unique(a, return_index=True, return_counts=True)
>>> idx[np.argmax(cnt)]
4
```

**EDIT**

To provide some context on what is going on... `np.unique` always returns a sorted array of unique values. The optional `return_index` provides another output array, with the index in which the first occurrence of each unique value happens. And the optional `return_counts` provides an extra output with the number of occurrences of each unique value. With those building blocks, all you need to do is return the item of the index array at the position where the highest count happens.

Comment: I think that would work. Please correct me if I'm wrong here. Are you first getting the counts for each value? Then, are you taking the value with the max count (which is the mode value) and returning its index? Sorry I'm just trying to understand what is going on here. Looks beautiful will try it later today and check as a solution if it works :)

Comment: Yes, that's basically it, added some more explanation to the answer, hope it makes sense.

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

What is it that makes one solution more 'elegant' than another?  Shortness? Speed? Cleverness?  Most Pythonic?  Numpy-onic?

To me speed is more important that compactness.  I can always make a solution more compact by wrapping it in a function call.  Actually robustness is even more important.

---

A non-numpy route is to use handy tools in `collections`, as sketched here:

```
In [342]: a = numpy.array([ 6, 3, 4, 1, 2, 2, 2])

In [343]: import collections
```

Use `Counter` to quickly get the mode (value):

```
In [344]: c=collections.Counter(a)
In [345]: c
Out[345]: Counter({2: 3, 1: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1, 6: 1})
In [347]: mode=c.most_common(1)[0][0]
In [348]: mode
Out[348]: 2
```

Use `defaultdict` to collect the locations all values:

```
In [349]: adict=collections.defaultdict(list)
In [350]: for i,v in enumerate(a):
    adict[v].append(i)
In [351]: adict[mode]
Out[351]: [4, 5, 6]
```

I could have searched `adict` for the longest list, but I suspect `Counter` is faster.

Actually, when I know the `mode`, all I need is `where` - just as your use of `stats` shows:

```
In [352]: np.where(a==mode)
Out[352]: (array([4, 5, 6], dtype=int32),)
```

In time tests on this small array, `Counter` wins.

```
In [358]: timeit stats.mode(a)[0][0]
1000 loops, best of 3: 337 µs per loop
In [359]: timeit collections.Counter(a).most_common(1)[0][0]
10000 loops, best of 3: 20 µs per loop
```

Another possible tool is `bincount`:

```
In [367]: np.bincount(a)
Out[367]: array([0, 1, 3, 1, 1, 0, 1], dtype=int32)
In [368]: timeit np.argmax(np.bincount(a))
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.29 µs per loop
```

and with the `where`:

```
In [373]: timeit np.where(a==np.argmax(np.bincount(a)))[0][0]
100000 loops, best of 3: 11.2 µs per loop
```

It's fast, but I'm not sure if it is general enough.

Comment: There is so much good stuff here - wish I'd seen it all six months ago!

Comment: Wow this is amazing stuff! Thanks hpaulj! I will try it later today with my partner and mark it as a solution if it works. I have no doubts that it will! P.S. I clarified elegance. Thanks for helping me clarify.

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks!